# Redirecting R output and graphs

Tags: r, latex, ggplot2

I use Sweave and LaTex to create reports from R output and graphs. But sometime it is required to have graphs in editable format. I tried `R2wd` package but it doesn't seem very flexible with `ggplot2`. I'd highly appreciate if someone point out me some efficient ways. Thanks

Comment: Oh I would love something like this. The best I've done is to make super-short R scripts that do nothing but produce a plot, so you can modify the script. But I would love it if there were a friendlier way (I work with people who don't program).

Comment: I may be misunderstanding this.  Can you clarify what you mean by "editable"?  E.g. do you want images saved to files?

Comment: Here by editable mean can be copied from one file to another.

Comment: This seems a duplicate of your question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7212627/redirecting-r-output-and-graphs asked roughly the same time.  I've posted an answer to that one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It really depends what you mean by "editable", and what kinds of files/endpoints you're talking about. There are a lot of discussions out there (e.g. [this R-help thread from 2006](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-mac/2006-November/003400.html)) about (1) the best options for generating figures to embed in Word (or PowerPoint, which is pretty much the same question) and (2) the best options for figures that can be edited (by which *I* mean that they can be modified by non-R-users, not just moved from file to file). The general conclusions I have seen are:

- PDF files: vector format, editable in Adobe Illustrator ($$$), only sorta-kinda-embeddable in MS Office documents
- Windows metafiles or extended metafiles (WMF/EMF): vector format, very limited support outside of the Windows platform. Somewhat wonky format, but MS Office-native. Will certainly have limited support for things like alpha channels (transparency).
- SVG: vector format. Very modern, editable in Inkscape (don't know where else), not particularly MS Office-compatible (I think). (Generatable at least via the `Cairo` package.)
- PNG: raster format, but very compact (you can make the resolution absurdly large and still have a reasonably small output file); probably the easiest/lowest-common-denominator solution if you only need portability and not editability.

As of R 2.13.0, Sweave can automatically generate both PDF and PNG files on the fly for each figure chunk.  If this is saved as document `foo.Rnw`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\SweaveOpts{png=TRUE,pdf=TRUE,eps=FALSE}
<<fig1,fig=TRUE>>=
plot(1:5,1:5,col=1:5,pch=16)
@

\end{document}
```

... then after `Sweave`ing your directory will contain the files `foo-fig1.png` and `foo-fig1.pdf`. I don't know if that answers your question, but your question isn't entirely clear ...

Answer (score 4):

The package `pgfSweave` links together Sweave with `tikzDevice`. tikzDevice uses the LaTeX tikz package to put the instructions to draw a plot into LaTeX code.  So you can copy the resulting code from one file to another.  `pgfSweave` also adds some handy features like cacheing.

You could also just output PDFs of your plots with `pdf()` and then insert the LaTeX code to load those plots as figures.  You lose the automated file management of Sweave that way though.